# R: time-weighted mean, bins and time records overlap

Tags: r

I have a set of pre-specified breaks,

```
breaks = 2:7
```

that form a set of bins: `(2,3] (3,4] (4,5] (5,6] (6,7]`. Then I have a dataset looking like this

```
set.seed(42)
data = cbind.data.frame(time = cumsum(abs(rnorm(10))), value = rnorm(10))
> data
       time      value
1  1.370958  1.3048697
2  1.935657  2.2866454
3  2.298785 -1.3888607
4  2.931648 -0.2787888
5  3.335916 -0.1333213
6  3.442040  0.6359504
7  4.953562 -0.2842529
8  5.048222 -2.6564554
9  7.066645 -2.4404669
10 7.129359  1.3201133
```

Where `time` is to be seen as the time when `value` is updated, thus value is piecewise constant. 
What is a clever way to compute the weighted average of `value` for each of the bins above? My desired result would look like this:

```
     bin      mean
1  (2,3] -0.546621
2  (3,4]       ...
```

where I calculated the time-weighted mean as

```
(data$time[3]-2) * data$value[3] + 
  (data$time[4]-data$time[3])*data$value[4] + 
  (3-data$time[5]) * data$value[5]
```

Note that the problem is to calculate the weighted mean from the borders of the bins. Otherwise I could just do a `weighted.mean` and choose the `weights` as `diff(data$time)`. The only possible strategy I came up with is to add rows to `data` where time is the break times and the previous value is copied, i.e:

```
> data.mod
       time      value
1  1.370958  1.3048697
2  1.935657  2.2866454
3  2.000001  2.2866454
4  2.298785 -1.3888607
5  2.931648 -0.2787888
6  3.000001 -0.2787888
7   ...
```

and then I `cut`, `split` and take `weighted.mean` and all works out. But the only way to add those rows is a slow loop and for my real data `length(breaks)` is anywhere between 500 and 20,000, `dim(data)[1]` is roughly 10,000 - 50,000 and I have to repeat this operation at least 2,000 times so speed is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One can use a [stepfun](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/stepfun.html) to calculate `data.mod`:

```
library(stats)

data <- read.table(
  header = TRUE,
  text =
 "time      value
  1.370958  1.3048697
  1.935657  2.2866454
  2.298785 -1.3888607
  2.931648 -0.2787888
  3.335916 -0.1333213
  3.442040  0.6359504
  4.953562 -0.2842529
  5.048222 -2.6564554
  7.066645 -2.4404669
  7.129359  1.3201133" )

breaks <- 2:7

f <- stepfun( x = data$time,
              y = c(data$value[1],data$value),
              right = FALSE )

t <- c( data$time , breaks )
v <- c( data$value, f(breaks) )
n <- order(t)

data.mod <- data.frame( time  = t[n],
                        value = v[n]  )

data.mod
# time      value
# 1  1.370958  1.3048697
# 2  1.935657  2.2866454
# 3  2.000000  2.2866454
# 4  2.298785 -1.3888607
# 5  2.931648 -0.2787888
# 6  3.000000 -0.2787888
# 7  3.335916 -0.1333213
# 8  3.442040  0.6359504
# 9  4.000000  0.6359504
# 10 4.953562 -0.2842529
# 11 5.000000 -0.2842529
# 12 5.048222 -2.6564554
# 13 6.000000 -2.6564554
# 14 7.000000 -2.6564554
# 15 7.066645 -2.4404669
# 16 7.129359  1.3201133
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of *dplyr* and *tidyr*, I would approach it as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(bin = gsub("\\(|\\]","",cut(time, floor(min(time)):ceiling(max(time))))) %>%
  separate(bin, c("start","end"), ",", remove=FALSE, convert=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(next.time = lead(time),
         next.value = lead(value)) %>%
  group_by(bin) %>%
  summarise(mn = (time[1]-start[1])*value[1] + 
              (time[n()]-time[1])*value[n()] + 
              (end[1]-next.time[n()])*next.value[n()]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  slice(2:(n()-1))
```

this gives:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

    bin         mn
  (chr)      (dbl)
1   2,3 -0.5466210
2   3,4  0.2937581
3   4,5 -0.1429546
4   5,6  2.4750141
```

Especially when speed and memory efficiency are an issue, you can do this also with the *data.table* package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, bin := gsub("\\(|\\]","",cut(time, floor(min(time)):ceiling(max(time))))
          ][, c("start","end") := tstrsplit(bin, ",", fixed=TRUE, type.convert = TRUE)
            ][, `:=` (next.time = shift(time, type="lead"), next.value = shift(value, type="lead"))
              ][, .(mn = (time[1]-start[1])*value[1] + 
                      (time[.N]-time[1])*value[.N] + 
                      (end[1]-next.time[.N])*next.value[.N]), 
                by = bin][2:(.N-1)][]
```

which gives the same result:

```
   bin         mn
1: 2,3 -0.5466210
2: 3,4  0.2937581
3: 4,5 -0.1429546
4: 5,6  2.4750141
```